# Calculating time passed since a textual date/time value

Tags: php

I have a database from which I extract this date/time value: `2018-01-19 09:50:54`

I want to print how many hours and minutes passed since that date, with regard to current server time:

I try this code:

```
$prev_date = "2018-01-19 09:50:54" // extracted from DB

$date_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 24-hour date-time, matches DB format

$interval = $prev_date->diff($date_now); // I saw this on another thread 

echo $interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function diff() on a non-object (on the
>   $interval=.... line )

I guess it is some kind of formatting problem, how do I fix that?

Comment: [This answer will be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/8913537)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$prev_date` is not a object. You need to transform to a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to use diff. Also, `date()` will return a string, you must use a DateTime object for this to be able to use `diff` function.

```
$prev_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2018-01-19 09:50:54');

$date_now = new DateTime(); // 24-hour date-time, matches DB format

$interval = $prev_date->diff($date_now); // I saw this on another thread 

echo $interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";
```

Comment: For testing I'm trying to echo '$date_now = new DateTime();' to see it really gives current server time, but I'm getting an error..

Comment: `$date_now` is a object now. You can't "echo", try using `var_dump($date_now);` instead. Or you can use `echo $date_now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`